# Starting Redis in systemd with Auth

Tags: systemd, redis

Does anyone know how to pass the auth to redis "when it is started in systemd." You have to use a custom init script here. Mine is the following:

```
[Unit] 
Description = Redis In-Memory Store 
After = network.target

[Service] 
User = redis 
ExecStart = /www/redis/redis-4.0.11/src/redis-server /www/redis/tests/redis.conf 
ExecStop = /www/redis/redis-4.0.11/src/redis-cli shutdown 
RestartSec = 3s 
Restart = on-success

[Install] 
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

I know how to do it if I use the redis_init_script found in redis/utils, but it has to be placed in the /etc/init.d. It does not work when placed in the lib/systemd/system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a systemd service override for this. For example:

```
# systemctl edit redis.service

[Service]
ExecStop=
ExecStop=/www/redis/redis-4.0.11/src/redis-cli -a mypassword shutdown
```

The first `ExecStop=` is necessary to discard the list of `ExecStop=` commands from the original unit.

---

Note that this is a custom redis systemd unit. The redis systemd unit that ships with Fedora (and the identical package built by [remi](https://rpms.remirepo.net/) for RHEL/CentOS) calls a shutdown script that reads the password from redis.conf and automatically passes it in redis-cli, so no customization is necessary. You might wish to use the distribution redis, or at least study its scripts.